# Can std::function be a class data member?

Tags: c++, function, class

I have the simple following code:

```
template<class R, class... Args> class CallBack {
protected:
    std::function<R(Args...)> myFunc;

public:
    CallBack(std::function<R(Args...)> funcIn) : myFunc(funcIn) {}

    virtual ~CallBack() {}

    R call(Args... args) {
        return myFunc(args...);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::function<int(int,int)> tmp = [](int y, int z){return y + z + 2;};
    CallBack<int(int,int)> x(tmp);
    std::cout << x.call(12, 7);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it just doesn't work. I get:

```
../src/main.cpp:17:28: error: function returning a function
  std::function<R(Args...)> myFunc;
                            ^
```

I checked the prototype of std::function, and it is a simple class, so why couldn't I use it as an attribute for my class `CallBack`?

In my main I can instanciate an object of type `std::function<int(int,int)>`, so what is the difference? Are their special restrictions with `std::function`?

Comment: What is a class attribute?

Comment: try this `return myFunc( std::forward<Args>(args...) );`

Comment: You have a typo: `CallBack<int(int,int)>` should be `CallBack<int, int, int>`.

Comment: Or your class should be something like `template <typename > class CallBack; template<class R, class... Args> class CallBack<R(Args...)> {/*..*/};`

Comment: @Jarod42: You are right, I attempted to mimic std::function but just forgot the end of its declaration...

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. In definition `template<class R, class... Args> class CallBack` - `R` matches `int(int,int)` and `Args...` is empty.

You would have to do something like this, if you want exactly this signature of `CallBack`:

```
CallBack<int,int,int> x(tmp);
```

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot!